# 'Sampling Error' in Eo

Tags: single-word-requests

How can the expression '[sampling error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_error)' in statistics be translated in Esperanto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eraro de specimeno; specimena eraro; specimeneraro.

Comment: Google translate even gave a verb form `speciminado` for _sampling_, from whatever source.